# Redux Dev tools updating. Console not updating with state changes or data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Ive been trying to do this with react hooks and the useSelector/useDispatch. What happens is, I am able to see the data and state change in the Redux DevTools however, when logging to the console, I either get an empty array or undefined. I am also not able to render the data to the screen expectedly.

Posts Component

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
 import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {getPosts} from '../actions/postActions'


const Posts = props =>{

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const postData = useSelector(state=> state.items, []) || []; //memoization?
    const [items, setItems] = useState(postData)

    console.log(postData);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getPosts());
    }, []);

    return(    
        <h1>{postData[0]}</h1>
    )
}

export default Posts
```

ACTIONS

```
import {GET_POSTS, NEW_POSTS} from '../actions/types'

export const getPosts =()=> dispatch =>{
         //fetch
    console.log('fetching')

    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'

    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(posts=> dispatch({type: GET_POSTS, payload: posts}))
}
```

[reduxDevTools image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF48L.png)

Comment: What does your reducer look like?

Comment: Your action should just return a plain object. You have dispatched your action twice. Try to return a plain object and not dispatch it in your ACTION file.

Comment: @PrateekOraon where are they dispatching the action twice?

Comment: Not actually dispatching but using dispatch twice. First in useEffect and then in ACTION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is coming from this line:

```
const postData = useSelector(state=> state.items, []) || [];
```

If you want postData to initially be an array, it's best to set it as an array in your reducer.

**Working example** (click `Posts` tab to make API call):

[image: Edit Redux Thunk Hooks - API Calls]

---

**actions/postActions.js**

```
import api from "../utils/api";
import * as types from "../types";

export const getPosts = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: types.POSTS_FETCH });

    const res = await api.get("posts");

    dispatch({
      type: types.POSTS_SET,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: types.POSTS_FAILED_FETCH,
      payload: err.toString()
    });
  }
};
```

**reducers/postsReducer.js**

```
import * as types from "../types";

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  error: "",
  isLoading: true
};

export default (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case types.POSTS_FETCH:
      return initialState;
    case types.POSTS_SET:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: payload,
        error: "",
        isLoading: false
      };
    case types.POSTS_FAILED_FETCH:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload,
        isLoading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**containers/FetchPostsHooks/index.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getPosts } from "../../actions/postActions";
import Spinner from "../../components/Spinner";
import DisplayPosts from "../../components/DisplayPosts";

const Posts = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { isLoading, data, error } = useSelector(state => state.posts, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return isLoading ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : error ? (
    <p>{error}</p>
  ) : (
    <DisplayPosts data={data} />
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

Comment: Thanks everyone and @Matt for your assistance with. this I can now see the data as intended with the suggested changes to postData. I originally had the initialState in the reducer set to an empty array for items as well. Happy New Year!